# vertical line(boundary) issue in vegalite charts

Tags: vega-lite, vega-embed, vegas-viz

I create vertical line(boundary) in chart at any point of data provided by the user example [link of vertical line specs](https://vega.github.io/editor/?#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJghgLhIFygG4QDYFcCmBneBtUAwqhgHaQBO8IATAAy0CctAjCADQgAiGK81ArLWoBfNoWJkIlODXpNq7Ljz4AWABzNR4lKQpU6jWgGZF3XnGoB2AGwqtIIjsnTZhlaeUXr3+491T9OVp+D3MjWhU7MQcJPRkDJmtQ+CNwy19YgPigy2S4VMt+DKc41yY1PPDI4v8XBMY86hVLIxrnQMZmWkq6TWi-duzO1g4zPiN+Pu1ajoZmBVHPK2NhAF1REEQAYwB7Ei3oPFBSXbAASxIAc3hQAA8bkAAzM54wKgG9DigATwAHDCoJB2AFsLqgQMINigIN8MNJ8CATjtzlcHt8Hs9XlQxl8-gCZABHNAQEhQM4wMmIAGQjjAqQAaweUB2OxQZN+8Cg5EwuP+VBQF2p9iRKOuCBA93FkCgaGBs1ouQ26IQNJAdPIjPFzNZ7M53IwvPxIG5Ogha3NQA)

now, I tried to put the value in encoding.x.dataum in such way that vertical line got disappear example in this i put empty string but it is still making vertical line [editor link](https://vega.github.io/editor/?#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJghgLhIFygG4QDYFcCmBneBtUAwqhgHaQBO8IATAAy0CctAjCADQgAiGK81ArLWoBfNoWJkIlODXpNq7Ljz4AWABzNR4lKQpU6jWgGZF3XnGoB2AGwqtIIjsnTZhlaeUXr3+491T9OVp+D3MjWhU7MQcJPRkDJmtQ+CNwy19YgPigy2S4VMt+DKc41yY1PPDI4v8XBMY86hVLIxrnQMZmWkq6TWi-duzO1g4zPiN+Pu1ajoZmBVHPK2NhAF1REEQAYwB7Ei3oPFBSXbAASxIAc3hQAA8bkAAzM54wKgG9DigATwAHDCoJB2AFsLqgQMINigIN8MNJ8CATjtzlcHt8Hs9XlQxl8-gCZABHNAQEhQM4wMmIAGQjjAqQAaweUB2OxQZN+8Cg5EwuP+VBQF2p9iRKOuCBA93FkCgaGBVAhHHRCBpIDp5EZ4uZrPZnO5GF5+JA3J0ELWZqAA) .
Please help me by providing such a value to put in encoding.x.dataum such that the line will not show but the layer exists. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could also do it like this:

Change the transform filter for a date you want or set it to null if you want it hidden.

But setting x.datum will not work.

```
{
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {"Calendar": "200901", "Del": 2502},
      {"Calendar": "200902", "Del": 2481},
      {"Calendar": "200903", "Del": 2764},
      {"Calendar": "200904", "Del": 2666},
      {"Calendar": "200905", "Del": 3044},
      {"Calendar": "200906", "Del": 3307},
      {"Calendar": "200907", "Del": 3375},
      {"Calendar": "200908", "Del": 3044},
      {"Calendar": "200909", "Del": 2473},
      {"Calendar": "200910", "Del": 3201},
      {"Calendar": "200911", "Del": 2351},
      {"Calendar": "200912", "Del": 2703}
    ]
  },
  
  "vconcat": [
    {
      "encoding": {"x": {"field": "Calendar", "type": "nominal"}},
      "layer": [
        {
          "encoding": {"y": {"field": "Del", "type": "quantitative"}},
          "mark": {"tooltip": true, "type": "line"}
        },
        {
          "transform":  [{"filter": "datum.Calendar == 200910"}],
          "mark": {"tooltip": true, "type": "rule", "color": "red"}
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: thanks again for your solution but i can only put value in encoding.x.datum.. please tell me such a value which help me to do the same.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your line to "disappear" then you could just set the color to transparent. "color": "transparent"

```
{
"encoding": {"x": {"datum": "200907"}, "y": {}},
"mark": {"tooltip": true, "type": "rule", "color": "transparent"}         
}
```

```
{
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {"Calendar": "200901", "Del": 2502},
      {"Calendar": "200902", "Del": 2481},
      {"Calendar": "200903", "Del": 2764},
      {"Calendar": "200904", "Del": 2666},
      {"Calendar": "200905", "Del": 3044},
      {"Calendar": "200906", "Del": 3307},
      {"Calendar": "200907", "Del": 3375},
      {"Calendar": "200908", "Del": 3044},
      {"Calendar": "200909", "Del": 2473},
      {"Calendar": "200910", "Del": 3201},
      {"Calendar": "200911", "Del": 2351},
      {"Calendar": "200912", "Del": 2703}
    ]
  },
  "vconcat": [
    {
      "encoding": {"x": {"field": "Calendar", "type": "nominal"}},
      "layer": [
        {
          "encoding": {"y": {"field": "Del", "type": "quantitative"}},
          "mark": {"tooltip": true, "type": "line"}
        },
        {
          "encoding": {"x": {"datum": "200907"}, "y": {}},
          "mark": {"tooltip": true, "type": "rule", "color": "transparent"}
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: thanks for your solution but i can only put value in encoding.x.datum.. please tell me such a value which help me to do the same..

Comment: Why are you limited to that?